# Point of Sale Schema Design problem in Django App

Tags: mysql, django, database, postgresql, database-design

From these models (Below) i am having a Design problem while creating this application, as i am not an expert in Database Design, so i thought to take some Expert opinion about this matter.Let me explain this issue.

As you can see there is SaleItem Model which contains product_id as Foreign key. Now issues are..

1. If user delete a product which is present in SaleItem table then it will Raise integrity violation issue or some how, if we allow to delete product, then product relation will break and we will not be able to run queries which relates to product.
2. If User Update Product name from A to B or changes its price, then it
   going to effect the Sold items.

I tried my best to explain the scenario but if something is left please ask me in comments.

Thank you

```
class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    franchise = models.ForeignKey(Franchise, default=None, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=False, null=False)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=False, null=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=False, null=False)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=None)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    units_in_stock = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    manufacture_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    expire_date = models.DateField()
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True, blank=True, null=True)


class Sale(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sales'

    franchise = models.ForeignKey(Franchise, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)


class SaleItem(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sale_items'

    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=None)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

Comment: So, what do you expect to happen when you delete a Product with Saleitem object related to it? should those SaleItems be deleted? or stay there with null values? or something else?

Comment: null values will not help, then i cannot query back to its relations... 
one solution remove product_id from SaleItem table and add some columns from Product like sale_price, discount, purchase_price in SaleItem but then its a bad practice ... 
Is there any other solution ..?

Comment: Yes, a better practice is to have a DeletedProduct table which holds your deleted products, or even better, to just have an is_deleted Boolean field on the Product that you would just set/unset based on the status of that product. And then you can easily just filter on Products that are is_deleted=False, and this way you wont loose any relational data, and better you can later implement history for you reports :)

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Yes, i t was in consideration .. but i was still want to take some opinion about it.. 
but still it helped .. 
Thank you

Comment: Great to hear that. I would also be interested to know what other options one would have in this case.